# JavaFx - is there any way to refresh whole treeview?

Tags: javafx, treeview, refresh

I'm newbie on java fx.
And I'm making an application with treeview and treeview has made by nested set model. So each treeitem has to have left, right data.(I made a treeitem like Treeitem>. Object has data(id, label name, left, right, etc) and String is label name to be shown at treeview.)

The problem is that whole treeitems have to be updated when I add a new treeitem(or delete treeitem). I already implemented whole data(the other treeitem's) to be updated on DB, but treeview still has data isn't updated.

I looked for the way to refresh treeview, but I just found user shouldn't use updateitem forcefully.

Is there any way or method to refresh whole treeview?

FYI. code below

```
Pair<LabelTreeItem,String> f = new Pair<>(new LabelTreeItem(1, "Root", 0, 0, "",0), "Root");

    try {
        f = new Pair<>(service.getRoot(), "Root");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find Root Node");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TreeItem<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>> root = createNode(f);
    root.setExpanded(true);
    treeView.setRoot(root);
    treeView.setEditable(true);


    treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>>,TreeCell<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>>>(){
        @Override
        public TreeCell<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>> call(TreeView<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>> p) {              
            return new TextFieldTreeCellImpl();             
        }
    });
```

.....................................

```
private TreeItem<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>> createNode(final Pair<LabelTreeItem,String> f) {
    return new TreeItem<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>>(f) {
        private boolean isLeaf;
        private boolean isFirstTimeChildren = true;
        private boolean isFirstTimeLeaf = true;

        @Override public ObservableList<TreeItem<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>>> getChildren() {
            if (isFirstTimeChildren) {
                isFirstTimeChildren = false;
                super.getChildren().setAll(buildChildren(this));
            }
            return super.getChildren();
        }

        @Override public boolean isLeaf() {
            if (isFirstTimeLeaf) {
                isFirstTimeLeaf = false;
                Pair<LabelTreeItem,String> f = getValue();

                int nodeLeft = f.getKey().getLeft();
                int nodeRight = f.getKey().getRight();

                if(nodeRight-nodeLeft == 1) {
                    isLeaf = true;
                    System.out.println("this is leaf");
                }
            }

            return isLeaf;
        }

        private ObservableList<TreeItem<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>>> buildChildren(TreeItem<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>> TreeItem) {
            Pair<LabelTreeItem,String> f = TreeItem.getValue();
            System.out.println("ID: "+f.getKey().getId());


            int nodeLeft = f.getKey().getLeft();
            int nodeRight = f.getKey().getRight();

            try {

                if (f != null && nodeRight-nodeLeft != 1) {
                    ArrayList<LabelTreeItem> item = new ArrayList<>();
                    item = service.getChildren(f.getKey().getLeft(), f.getKey().getRight(), f.getKey().getDepth());
                    ArrayList<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int i=0; i<item.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println("test : " + item.get(i).getLabel());

                        Pair<LabelTreeItem,String> pair = createPair(item.get(i), item.get(i).getLabel());
                        itemList.add(pair);
                    }

                    if(itemList.size() != 0) {
                        ObservableList<TreeItem<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>>> children = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                        for (Pair<LabelTreeItem,String> childNode : itemList) {
                            children.add(createNode(childNode));
                        }

                        return children;
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
        }
    };
}

private Pair<LabelTreeItem, String> createPair(LabelTreeItem item, String name) {
    return new Pair<>(item, name);
}
```

LabelTreeItem.java

```
public class LabelTreeItem {
private int id;
private String label;
private int left;
private int right;
private String comment;
private int depth;

public LabelTreeItem(int id, String label, int left, int right, String comment, int depth) {
    this.id = id;
    this.label = label;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.depth = depth;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public int getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeft(int left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public int getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setRight(int right) {
    this.right = right;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public int getDepth() {
    return depth;
}

public void setDepth(int depth) {
    this.depth = depth;
}
}
```

TextFieldTreeCellImpl.java

```
public TextFieldTreeCellImpl() {
    service = SqliteService.getInstance();
    MenuItem addLabel = new MenuItem("Label add");
    addMenu.getItems().add(addLabel);
    addLabel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            getTreeItem().setExpanded(true);

            LabelTreeItem newItem = null;
            try {
                id = getTreeItem().getValue().getKey().getId();
                label = getTreeItem().getValue().getKey().getLabel();
                depth = getTreeItem().getValue().getKey().getDepth()+1;
                left = getTreeItem().getValue().getKey().getLeft();
                right = getTreeItem().getValue().getKey().getRight();

                newItem = service.getData("New Label", id,depth);
                TreeItem<Pair<LabelTreeItem,String>> newLabel = new TreeItem(createPair(newItem, newItem.getLabel()));
                getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newLabel);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    MenuItem editLabel = new MenuItem("Label modify");
    addMenu.getItems().add(editLabel);
    editLabel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            startEdit();
        }
    });

    MenuItem removeLabel = new MenuItem("Label delete");
    addMenu.getItems().add(removeLabel);
    removeLabel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                left = getTreeItem().getValue().getKey().getLeft();
                right = getTreeItem().getValue().getKey().getRight();
                service.deleteData(left, right, (right-left)+1);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            getTreeItem().getParent().getChildren().remove(getTreeItem());

            System.out.println("Remove");
        }
    });
}

@Override 
protected void updateItem(final Pair<LabelTreeItem, String> pair, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(pair, empty);

    if (!empty && pair != null) {
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (textField != null) {
                textField.setText(getString());
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
        } else {

            setText(pair.getKey().getLabel());
            setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
            setContextMenu(addMenu);
        }
    } else {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(pair !=null){
                Tooltip tTip = new Tooltip(pair.getKey().getLabel());
                tTip.uninstall(getTreeView(), tTip);
            }
        }
    });

    setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(pair !=null){
                Tooltip tTip = new Tooltip();
                tTip.setText(pair.getKey().getLabel()
                        +"\nComment : "+pair.getKey().getComment()
                        +"\nLeft : "+pair.getKey().getLeft()
                        +"\nRight : "+pair.getKey().getRight());
                tTip.setFont(new Font("Arial", 16));
                tTip.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");
                tTip.centerOnScreen();
                tTip.install(getTreeView(), tTip);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

DB Table

```
id|label|left|right|comment|depth
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of your `TreeCellImpl`, which I assume extends `TreeCell<Pair<LabelTreeItem, String>>`? What does the `updateItem(...)` look like?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I edited the post and added updateItem().